# Store cron job logs in a file Php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am trying to get my cron jobs log in a log file. unfortunately i am not able to achieve that and i cant find any tutorial/blog about this.

I am using latest laravel version and i wrote 1 cron job

This is my command file handle

```
public function handle()
    {
        Employee::where('id', 2)->update(['salary' => 0]);

        $this->info('Command:Update Run successfully!');
    }
```

and this is my schedule

```
$schedule->command('command:update')
        ->everyMinute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In cron job command do this.This will create logs of cron in queue.log.

```
/usr/local/bin/<ea-php71> /home/<domain>/public_html/artisan queue:listen 1>> public_html/queue.log 2>&1
```

Here **ea-php71** is for php version 7.1.You can find this for other php versions.

Answer (score -1):

Have a try

add on top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
```

and use in your code like

```
public function handle()
{
    Log::info('cron has just started...');
    Employee::where('id', 2)->update(['salary' => 0]);
    $this->info('Command:Update Run successfully!');
    Log::info('... and now cron has ended ');
}
```

You will find the logs according what you have configured in your `.env` at `LOG_CHANNEL` and according to that what is configured in your `config/logging.php`

---

added for logging db stuff

---

Sure, i do this the following way: In my `AppServiceProvider.php` i have in the `boot` function this:

```
        if (config('database.log_querys') === true) {
            DB::listen(static function ($query) {
                Log::debug($query->sql, [$query->bindings, $query->time]);
            });
        }
```

and in my `config` and `env` i have triggers to either log all db querys or not

On top of this, i use https://logcrawler.de to watch all logs centralized

Comment: almost this is what i am looking for.... can you know how to show the query result also in log file ?

Comment: well let me try this and i hope it will work perfect

Comment: sir can you please tell me how to configure logccrawler with local project... I am trying this but not able to connect successfully Thank you

Comment: create a project, then look at your project overview and click on "edit project", there you will find detailed instructions for this.